# Remap Control_R in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp, ubuntu-12.04, key-bindings

I would like to rebind Right Control to BackSpace (or 'pipe/backslash').  I would prefer to do this with emacs lisp, but am open to other solutions. (I tried doing this with xmodmap but it didn't work)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an xmodmap solution. Put this in ~/.Xmodmap:

```
keycode 105 = BackSpace NoSymbol BackSpace
```

Use this to update instantly:

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

If you want pipe/backslash instead, just put:

```
keycode 105 = backslash bar backslash bar
```

The keycode is the same one.

Finally, the last way to interpret your question:

```
keycode 94 = Control_R NoSymbol Control_R
add Control = Control_R
```

This one puts `Control_R` where backslash/pipe used to be.

Comment: that solution binds backspace action to the keyboard Control_R key.